# Canvas Drawing issue in mozila browser

Tags: javascript, canvas, mozilla

i am just wondering my web application has a dragging chart and i just noticed that when i tried to run it in mozila browser the drawing is slower compared to other major browser. my question is what is the cause of this? is there a technique to make it faster? my drawing is like this in canvas

```
CanvasContext.beginPath();
CanvasContext.moveTo(0,0);
CanvasContext.lineTo(500,500);
CanvasContext.stroke();
```

something like that. and it is really slower as in really slow in mozila.
Anyone know why??

Comment: The code you provided is not slow. It's the by-the-book. Might be some other part of your drawing logic that might overdo things.

Comment: Open your chrome dev tools, start recording the JS profiler, drag your chart-handler or whatever interaction makes your drawing slow, stop recording and inspect the Profile and timeline results and Take action toward the functions and methods that might compromise your speed.

Comment: is the mozila really slower when it comes to drawing in canvas? i dont really have a problem in other browsers only in mozila

Comment: @Don, mozilla is slightly slower than chrome, even I have noticed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like I said in the comment, firefox is slower,

the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/canvas-drawing-performance) test results:

***firefox: `25,003 ops/sec`

  chrome:  `168,670 ops/sec`***

to see that visually, you can see [this beautiful link](http://www.madore.org/~david/.tmp/e8nowebgl.html).

apparanty, it is already posted as [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722186) in bugzilla.

**Edit** seems like they have fixed the issue in latest Firefox(v45).

Comment: The link that you provided is very useful thank you for that really appreciate it.